# alargar altura de las letras con CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

Bien, no se si esto es posible.
Tengo un texto cualquiera, con una fuente X.

Lo que quiero es que estas letras se muestren en mi pagina pero estiradas... como alargadas... [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Algo asi... ¿alguna idea de cómo lograrlo?

Comment: No es posible hacerlo con css, tendrás que usar Vectores SVG o bien usar alguna fuente con ese estilo, por cierto, te invito a leer [ask]

Comment: http://www.forosdelweb.com/f53/estirar-texto-con-css-1031554/ Aqui hablan de la propiedad font-stretch, echale un vistazo quizas te sirva

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No es posible cambiar el *alargar* la palabra, pero puedes *contraerla*

con `transform: scale()` puedes hacer la letra con un `font-size` enorme y después cambiarle el `width` en `scale`, de esta forma la letra da la ilusión de estar estirada por ejemplo `transform: scale(.1, 1);`

```css
.title1 {
  text-align:center;
  font-size: 300px;
  height: 110px;
  transform: scale(.1, 1);
  margin:0;
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:center;
}
.title2 {
  font-size: 500px;
  height:350px;
  transform: scale(.1, 1);
  margin:0;
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:center;
}
```

```html
<p class="title1">Hello</p>
<p class="title2">Autumn</p>
```

Comment: ¿Eres Dios? Muchas gracias! Me sirvió muchísimo!